# ASP.NET TextBox Validation Without TextBox Focus

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox, a datetimepicker (third party component) and a requiredvalidator (for datetimepicker). I want to validate if user fill the textbox (length > 0), then requiredvalidator enabled is true, but if user not fill the textbox or textbox is empty, then requiredvalidator enabled is false.

The problem is when user entering edit form (data fill by server side) and the textbox is not empty but datetimepicker is null/empty (old data before migration), javascript validation is not work, except I click the textbox (focus) and click save button.

this is my TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtS" runat="server" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" CausesValidation="true" BorderWidth="1px" Width="170px" OnBlur="ValidatorEnabledDisabled(this.value);" onchange="ValidatorEnabledDisabled(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>

<dxe:ASPxDateEdit ID="DateEditExpiredDate" runat="server" Width="174px" CssClass="TextFlat" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2003 Silver/{0}/styles.css" CssPostfix="Office2003_Silver" ImageFolder="~/App_Themes/Office2003 Silver/{0}/" EditFormatString="dd/MMM/yyyy" EditFormat="Custom"></dxe:ASPxDateEdit>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvDateEditExpiredDate" ControlToValidate="DateEditExpiredDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Ex expired date is required" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidatorEnabledDisabled(value) {
            if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
                var Exp = document.getElementById('<%=rfvDateExpiredDate.ClientID%>');

                if (value.length > 0) {
                    Exp.enabled = true;
                } else {
                    Exp.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Are there another solution without use OnClientClick event ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: show code, its how we help.

Comment: put the js code on page load event and get the value directly from textbox var TxtSID= document.getElementById('<%=TxtS.ClientID%>');
then check if it is empty or not

Comment: @NazirUllah: You mean check it on server side? I need client side.

Comment: no i means client side , client side load event are $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: whats the problem in calling validation function on save/update button click and textbox  textchange event ??

Comment: @NazirUllah: if textchange event is server side, its need postback. I want to minimize postback. and if textchange event (onchange) is client side, it did not work and need focus to textbox.